# Phase diagram of $\text{He}^3$ at low temperatures

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, phase-diagram, low-temperature-physics

The $p(T)$ phase diagram of $\text{He}^3$ at low temperatures is given here:
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomerantschuk-Effekt#/media/File:Phasendiagramm_He3log.gif

How can one physically explain that for the solidification curve it holds $\frac{dP}{dT} = 0$ at $T = 0$?

One idea would be to use $\frac{dP}{dT} = \frac{\Delta s}{\Delta v}$, but why is the entropy difference between the liquid and the solid state $\Delta s = s_l - s_s$ zero?